# Milk & Meat by milk of a dead cow?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, issur-vheter

Someone told me today that they thought it was permitted to mix milk and meat if the milk was extracted from a dead cow (ie by cooking its udder). However I was unable to confirm in my googling. Has anyone heard of this?

Comment: I imagine they had in mind Y.D. 90:1, but "mutar" is an overstatement.

Comment: why would milk from a dead cow be muter?

Comment: Where do folks eat cow udders?  Is it considered a delicacy or specialty somewhere? Sounds(sorry, can't resist) udderly gross as a meal.:)

Comment: @Laser123 if it was inside the cow when it died it could be considered part of the dead cow, and fleishig.

Comment: @eliyahu exactly and dead cow is treif

Comment: assume it was shechted kosherly.

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect, with a minor exception; if you **accidentally** cooked or roasted an udder **by itself** in its own milk, you would be allowed to eat it.

Some details:

The Shulchan Aruch in [סימן צ - דיני כחל](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_15.html#HtmpReportNum0003_L2) says that one may not cook the udder if there is still milk inside.

It's a Rabbinical prohibition, and therefore if you transgressed the Rabbinical prohibition and cooked or roasted the udder with its own milk, you may eat it.

However, you may not cook it with anything else. if you did cook it with other things, then you'd need 60 times the amount of permissible food in the pot to be allowed to eat it.

> **א** הַכְּחָל (פי' הַדַּד שֶׁל הַבְּהֵמָה), אָסוּר מִדִּבְרֵי סוֹפְרִים, שֶׁאֵין בָּשָׂר שֶׁנִּתְבַּשֵׁל בַּחֲלֵב שְׁחוּטָה אָסוּר מִן הַתּוֹרָה. לְפִיכָךְ, **אִם קְרַעוֹ וּמֵרֵק הֶחָלָב שֶׁבּוֹ, מֻתָּר לִצְלוֹתוֹ וּלְאָכְלוֹ**. וְאִם קְרָעוֹ שְׁתִי וָעֵרֶב, וְטָחוֹ בַּכֹּתֶל עַד שֶׁלֹּא נִשְׁאֲרָה בּוֹ לַחְלוּחִית חָלָב, מֻתָּר לְבַשְּׁלוֹ עִם הַבָּשָׂר. וּכְחָל שֶׁלֹּא קְרָעוֹ, בֵּין שֶׁל קְטַנָּה שֶׁלֹּא הֵינִיקָה בֵּין שֶׁל גְּדוֹלָה, אָסוּר לְבַשְּׁלוֹ. **וְאִם עָבַר וּבִשְּׁלוֹ**, (א) **בִּפְנֵי עַצְמוֹ, וְכָל שֶׁכֵּן אִם צְלָאוֹ, מֻתָּר לְאָכְלוֹ**. וְאִם בִּשְּׁלוֹ עִם בָּשָׂר אַחֵר, מְשַׁעֲרִין אוֹתוֹ (ב) בְּשִׁשִּׁים, וּכְחָל מִן הַמִּנְיָן. כֵּיצַד, אִם הָיָה הַכֹּל עִם הַכְּחָל כְּמוֹ שִׁשִּׁים בַּכְּחָל, (ג) הַכְּחָל אָסוּר וְהַשְׁאָר מֻתָּר. וְאִם הָיָה בְּפָחוֹת מִשִּׁשִּׁים, הַכֹּל אָסוּר. בֵּין כָּךְ וּבֵין כָּךְ, אִם נָפַל לִקְדֵרָה אַחֶרֶת, אוֹסֵר אוֹתָהּ, וּמְשַׁעֲרִין בּוֹ בְּס' כְּבָרִאשׁוֹנָה; שֶׁהַכְּחָל עַצְמוֹ שֶׁנִּתְבַּשֵׁל נַעֲשָׂה כַּחֲתִיכָה הָאֲסוּרָה. וְאֵין מְשַׁעֲרִין בּוֹ אֶלָּא כְּמוֹת שֶׁהוּא בְּעֵת שֶׁנִּתְבַּשֵׁל, לֹא כְּמוֹת שֶׁהָיָה בַּשָׁעָה שֶׁנָּפַל. *הגה: וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים דְּאִם נָפַל תְּחִלָּה לִקְדֵרָה שֶׁאֵין בָּהּ ס', (ד) וְנֶאֱסַר הַכְּחָל, אִם נָפַל אַחַר כָּךְ לִקְדֵרָה אַחֶרֶת, אֵין הַכְּחָל מִצְטָרֵף לְס' (טוּר בְּשֵׁם הָרַשְׁבָּ''א וד''ע לְר''ן דְּלֹא כבֵּית יוֹסֵף לר''ן), וְכֵן עִקָּר.*‏
>
> באר היטב  (א) **עצמו**. פי' הש''ך היינו בלא בשר אבל פשיטא דבמים וירקות ושאר דברים חשוב כבישול בפני עצמו: (ב) **בששים**. כתב הש''ך ולא משערינן במאי דנפיק מיניה דלא ידעינן כמה נפק וע''ל סי' ס''ט סי''א: (ג) **האסורה**. כתב הט''ז בשם הרשב''א הטעם שאסורה הכחל כשיהיה ס' לפי שאנו חוששין שמא לא פלט כל חלבו בקדרה ראשונה ועדיין נשאר קצת חלב בתוך הכחל לפיכך חוזר ואוסר כבתחלה והר''ן כתב שאינה אסורה אלא משום מראית עין ולזה נוטה דעת הט''ז ע''ש (עוד כ' שם דלדידן דקי''ל בכל האיסורים חנ''נ כן אפילו באיסור דרבנן וראייתו מרמ''א כאן): (ד) **הכחל**. כתב הש''ך מ''ש הב''ח דכחל הוי בריה כמו ג''ה הוא תמוה דאיתא בש''ס ופוסקים דלא הוי בריה אלא מה שנאסר מתחלת ברייתו וכן מבואר ברמב''ם דג''ה הוי בריה וכחל לא הוי בריה ע''ש:‏

More so, the custom is to not cook it - even without its milk - with other meat.

> **ב** נָהֲגוּ שֶׁלֹּא לְבַשְּׁלוֹ עִם בָּשָׂר כְּלָל. וּלְבַשְּׁלוֹ בְּלֹא בָּשָׂר, (ה) בְּטִגּוּן אוֹ בְּפַשְׁטִידָ'' א, מַצְרִיכִין קְרִיעָה שְׁתִי וָעֵרֶב וְטִיחָה בַּכֹּתֶל; וּלְצָלִי, קְרִיעָה שְׁתִי וָעֵרֶב. *הגה: וְאִם עָבַר וּבִשְּׁלוֹ, אִם קְרָעוֹ שְׁתִי וָעֵרֶב וְטָחוֹ בַּכֹּתֶל, יֵשׁ לְהַתִּיר בְּדִיעֲבַד (סה''ת וְהַמָּרְדְּכַי וְהַגָּהוֹת מַיְמוֹנִי וְהַטּוּר וְעוֹד פּוֹסְקִים עת''ח) בִּמְקוֹם הֶפְסֵד (ו) מְרֻבֶּה, אֲבָל בְּלָאו הָכֵי אֵין לְהַתִּיר*... ... ‏